# Cannot generate model class adapter with build_runner

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have transformed my model "note" into hive model in order to store some data with hive. I'm trying to generate model class adapter with command "flutter pub run build_runner build", but it has no effect. Generated file with adapter, which I need, is not created.

Here is my transformed model "note.dart":

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'note.g.dart';

class Note extends HiveObject{
  @HiveType(typeId: 0)
  Note({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.content,
    required this.date,
    this.isPinned = false,
    this.isChecked = false,
  });

  @HiveField(0)
  late final DateTime id;

  @HiveField(1)
  late String title;

  @HiveField(2)
  late String content;

  @HiveField(3)
  late DateTime date;

  @HiveField(4)
  bool isPinned;

  @HiveField(5)
  bool isChecked;
}
```

Also I'm pasting my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  very_good_analysis: ^1.0.0
  hive: ^2.2.2
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner: ^2.1.11
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
```

And the output of command "flutter pub run build_runner build":
[command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRa4J.jpg)

I hope you can help me somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line   `@HiveType(typeId: 0)` to the top outside the class

Comment: It worked. I don't know why i placed it inside the class. I couldn't find this mistake for a while. Thanks!